# Missing content of field CreatorFullName and ModifierFullName in GeneralJournalEntryLines

Tags: exact-online, invantive-data-hub

The business object GeneralJournalEntryLines contains the GL transaction lines of Exact Online. For performance tuning reasons, we are changing our scripts that copy data from Exact Online to our on-premise database to only include changes where possible instead of a full copy.

However, a query on GeneralJournalEntries joined with GeneralJournalEntryLines sometimes returns a null value in CreatorFullName and ModifiedFullName.

I've tried to reproduce new rows with this problem but those work fine.

Is this a database corruption? Or a join fault on my side?

The Exact Online query is:

```
use <DIVISION CODE>

select GE.Created GE_Created
      ,GE.Division GE_Division
      ,GE.EntryID GE_EntryID
      ,GE.EntryNumber GE_EntryNumber
      ,GE.FinancialPeriod GE_FinancialPeriod
      ,GE.FinancialYear GE_FinancialYear
      ,GE.JournalCode GE_JournalCode
      ,GE.Modified GE_Modified
      ,GE.Reversal GE_Reversal
      ,GE.Status GE_Status
      ,GE.Type GE_Type
      ,GL.AccountCode GL_AccountCode
      ,GL.AmountDC GL_AmountDC
      ,GL.AmountVATDC GL_AmountVATDC
      ,GL.AssetCode GL_AssetCode
      ,GL.CostCenter GL_CostCenter
      ,GL.CostUnit GL_CostUnit
      ,GL.CreatorFullName GL_CreatorFullName
      ,GL.Date GL_Date
      ,GL.Description GL_Description
      ,GL.GLAccountCode GL_GLAccountCode
      ,GL.LineNumber GL_LineNumber
      ,GL.ModifierFullName GL_ModifierFullName
      ,GL.OurRef GL_OurRef
      ,GL.ProjectCode GL_ProjectCode
      ,GL.Quantity GL_Quantity
      ,GL.VATBaseAmountDC GL_VATBaseAmountDC
      ,GL.VATCode GL_VATCode
      ,GL.VATPercentage GL_VATPercentage
      ,GL.VATType GL_VATType
from       ExactOnlineREST..GeneralJournalEntries GE
inner join ExactOnlineREST..GeneralJournalEntryLines GL
on GE.EntryID=GL.EntryID
where GE.Status <> 50 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201501 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:09' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201502 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:09' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201503 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:09' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201504 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:09' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201505 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:08' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201506 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:03:08' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201507 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:27' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201508 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:27' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201509 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:27' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201510 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:26' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201511 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:27' ) ) 
or ( GE.Status = 50 and ( (GE.FinancialYear*100) + GE.FinancialPeriod = 201512 and GE.Modified > '09/01/2017 14:27:26' ) ) 

local export results as "D:\Invantive\data\uit_EOL\40570GeneralJournals.csv" format csv

local exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the query:

```
select * 
from   ExactOnlineREST..GeneralJournalEntryLines GL
where  gl.modifierfullname is null or gl.creatorfullname is null
```

it seems that all rows where the `modifiedfullname` or `creatorfullname` is missing have an associated user GUID from a short list. It are also (based on creation date) all records which are of considerable age.

It seems that Exact Online APIs internally make a left outer join with the users table, for which no longer active users return no information.

Comment: So your audit history just vanishes?

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes, it seems so. Unless you register the relationship GUID with name in another table by registering all new records in users table of Exact Online. Weird, would expect that users get disabled instead of deleted, but maybe German legislation or so.